# How can I allow the user "postgres" on one server to rsync to another?

Tags: ssh, rsync

I'm trying to get this command to work as the user postgres (so I can ship wal files):

```
rsync -a /tmp/test postgres@server2:/tmp/test
```

But I get the error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I've run `ssh-keygen` `` eval `ssh-agent` `` and `ssh-add` as postgres user on server1. keygen created `/var/lib/postgresql/.ssh/id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` and I can see that it's sent by using `ssh -vvv postgres@server2`.

On server2 I've created `/var/lib/postgresql/.ssh/authorized_keys` put the contents of id_rsa.pub form server1 in it. It's owned by postgres user and group and chmod 600. The `.ssh` directory is also owned by postgres and chmod 700.

I can see from verbose sshd logging on server2 that `Failed publickey for postgres...`

What am I missing? I'm guessing that sshd isn't looking at my authorized_keys file on server2

Comment: Gah! This was supposed to be on Serverfault. Moved there => http://serverfault.com/questions/469496

Answer (score -2):

Assuming your slave server allows key authentication, you only need to update `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` if you've set 'AllowedUsers', in which case you need to ensure `postgres` is in that list.

Other than that, just `ssh-keygen` (leave private key passphrase empty), and then add an `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` directory/file to the slave server. The home directory for `postgres` is `/var/lib/postgresql`, but if you do these operations while `su`'d as the `postgres` user, you can just use `~`, not to mention you won't have to `chown` anything, because `postgres` will own the generated ssh keys on the master server, and `postgres` will own the created directory/file on the slave server.

Be sure to set the file permissions securely on both the master and slave server:

## On master

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh

chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa

chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

chmod 600 ~/.ssh/known_hosts  # this one won't exist until you SSH once
```

## On slave

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh

chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```